# Mongo ruby driver: Running/getting mongostats/query Graphs

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am using mongo-ruby-driver, I want to get stats/query graphs to show for Mongo. But don't how can I get Mongostats/Graphs via mongo-ruby-driver.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than righting your own, you can just [set up MMS](http://www.10gen.com/mongodb-monitoring-service) and use that instead.

But, if you do want to pull the data directly, you can do that too - anything that can be run from the shell can be run from the driver.  So, for example, to run the stats() command, which translates on the command line to:

```
db.runCommand({dbstats : 1})
```

And so, just follow the guidelines at the top of the [ruby driver FAQ](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.1.5/file.FAQ.html) - the first one includes how to run any of the commands via the driver.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this does not solve my problem. It does gives me stats for a particular db like {"db":"humongo_test","collections":18,"objects":6793,"avgObjSize":1089.36081260121,"nsSizeMB":16,"ok":1.0}. That I can directly get via db.stats. What I need is output of `mongostat` command to show on browser screen.

Comment: Right, but you can also run: db.runCommand("serverStatus") - that should give you all the information you need, but you will have to poll it and calculate (diff from previous etc.) the results yourself to display it on a web page, which is essentially what mongostat is doing for the CLI.  There is currently no helper in the driver for it that I know of....